# excel vba compare & copy worksheets from 2 excel files

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

i've workbook 1 with 100 worksheets.
i've workbook 2 with 200 worksheets.

i need to perform 2 tasks:

- For those existing worksheets(same worksheet name in both books), i want to delete book 1 worksheet content (column A-Z) and copy content (column A-Z) from book 2 to book 1.
- For those missing worksheets in workbook 1, i want to copy the entire worksheet from book 2 to book 1.

pls advise if there are any existing online vba, thanks.

Comment: Looking for any code that you wrote would be nice too. Or should we do your homeworks instead?

Comment: thanks, mike, it does help to ease my problem

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First of all you need to loop through all your worksheets for both, open the 2 workbooks, and loop through both, then you can select them, compare if their name exists in the other worksheet, if not, you add it, otherwise, you copy the content from one to the other one and at the end you should save them. Solution in C#, see link for solution in VB.NET, something similiar is to apply for VBA.

```
Excel.Workbook workbook;
workbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("first file", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.Workbook workbook2;
workbook2 = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open("second file", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
{
    workbook.Activate();
    sheet.Activate();
    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet2 in workbook2.Sheets)
    {
         workbook2.Activate();
         sheet2.Activate();
         if(sheet2.Name.Equals(sheet.Name))
         {
             sheet.Range("A1:Z65535").Copy(Missing.Value);
             sheet2.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial(); // where cellmap = A1:Z65535
         }
         else
         {
             Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
             newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)this.Application.Worksheets.Add();
             sheet.Range("A1:Z65535").Copy(Missing.Value);
             newWorksheet.Range(cellmapp).PasteSpecial(); // where cellmap = A1:Z65535
             snewWorksheet.Range("A1:Z65535").Copy(Missing.Value);
             newWorksheet.Columns.AutoFit();
         }
    }
}
```

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=36c4611b-294a-4f87-a762-1016ad46d508

Comment: VBA and VB.NET are two completely different languages. Even if you translated the C# code to VB.NET, you wouldn't have something that would compile or be helpful in VBA.