# Excel Get data from other workbook file (with some data handling)

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make an Excel-document ("target document") that automatically updates with information from another Excel-document ("source document"). New data will be added to the source document from time to time and when the target document is opened it must contain the new data added to the source. Every new row in the source must be copied to the target, and every row has an "order number" which makes it unique and identifiable.

I can't use links because later changes in the source document shouldn't cause changes the target document.

How do I do this?

Edit: I was planning on doing this in VBA.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719498/excel-vba-compare-copy-worksheets-from-2-excel-files/17719799#17719799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can adapt and modify the code at http://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/04/26/export-data-one-excel-file-to-another-without-opening-them/ so that when the target workbook is opened, it updates data from the source workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this post, which I answered reccently. It has the same principe that you are looking for. [excel vba compare & copy worksheets from 2 excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719498/excel-vba-compare-copy-worksheets-from-2-excel-files/17719799#17719799)
You didn't tell us if you plan to do it in VB.NET/C# or VBA. The solution given is in C#/VB.NET translated.